# cache background image (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, caching

When i click on some link (link1 ...) it change body background with jquery function

```
 $("#link-home").click( function(){ $
    ("body").removeClass("bg2 bg3 bg4").addClass("bg1");
    });

    $("#link-link1").click( function(){ $
    ("body").removeClass("bg2 bg3 bg4").addClass("bg1");
    });

    $("#link-link2").click( function(){ $
    ("body").removeClass("bg1 bg3 bg4").addClass("bg2");
    });
```

Problem is when i refresh web page. It change background to default. There are two options how to do it. First use css only for change background ( i am trying it a few hours without result) or use cache. But how i can cache my background image? I tried [locache](http://locachejs.org/) . I added locache.js to head but it is not working.

Comment: You're only changing the background for the current window session. When you reload the page, it all starts fresh. If you want to persist data, you'll need to use cookies, localStorage, or a server-side method of storing and retrieving user preferences.

Comment: I know but http://locachejs.org/ is localStorage. But why it is not working? I do something bad? I only add .js file to my head.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to cache background image as the browser will cache it for you by default.
A simple solution would be:

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    var switchBackground = function(bg) {
        var savedBackgorund = window.localStorage.activeBackground;
        var bg = typeof bg !== 'undefined' ? bg :
            (savedBackground ? savedBackground : 'bg1');
        $('body').removeClass('bg1 bg2 bg3 bg4').addClass(bg);
        window.localStorage.activeBackground = bg;
    }

    switchBackground();

    $("#link-home").click( function() {
        switchBackground("bg1");
    });

    $("#link-link1").click( function() {
        switchBackground("bg1");
    });

    $("#link-link2").click( function() {
        switchBackground("bg2");
    });
});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for reply but it is not working for me. Where can be problem?

Comment: no errors, when i click on some link it do not change background. There is still default body background.